# Links Do Not Redirect User

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on my website, and I have come to an impasse: the links which I have created in my navigation bar do not redirect the user to another page on my site.

As can be seen [here](http://nmagerko.no-ip.org), I am using a simple navigation bar with a technique I found [at gmarwaha.com](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/). I tried to follow the instructions as best I could, but it seems I have missed a step - unfortunately I cannot figure out what that step is!

The CSS is a little different than what is on the site, but it still came from there, anyhow. It can be seen below:

```
.lavaLampBottomStyle {
    position: relative;
    height: 29px;
    width: 342px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }
        .lavaLampBottomStyle li {
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
        }
            .lavaLampBottomStyle li.back {
                border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
                width: 9px;
                height: 30px;
                z-index: 8;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .lavaLampBottomStyle li a {
                font: bold 14px arial;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000;
                outline: none;
                text-align: center;
                top: 7px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 0;
                z-index: 10;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                height: 30px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: auto 10px;
            }   
                .lavaLampBottomStyle li a:hover, .lavaLampBottomStyle li a:active, .lavaLampBottomStyle li a:visited {
                    border: none;
                }
```

The JavaScript placed in the `head` of my document is also very important:

```
$(function() {
$("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
fx: "backout",
speed: 700,
click: function(event, menuItem) {
return false;
}
});
});
```

If anyone would be able to aid me in finding this error, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the example code it's hard to tell but returning false from a click will prevent the action.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with that one. I didn't even think about that!